# Is it OK to send a 301 redirect with an action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, action-filter

I'm writing a new asp.net mvc application and I've been toying with the idea of allowing my user to post short, concise urls to content that he has posted. Those short url's will be handy in cramped spaces like Twitter and comment areas. I like this idea as I'm not a huge fan of url shorteners because they're so vague and you're never really sure what you're going to get. Instead of using a url shortener I want to give my client the ability to post:

`http://domain.com/p/234`

which does a 301 redirect to:

`http://domain.com/2009/08/10/this-is-the-content-title`

Now, this is a pretty simple process with a couple of extra routes and a custom ActionResult. The custom ActionResult I implemented is an extension method on a RedirectToRouteResult... It's fairly straightforward but about 20 lines of code nonetheless. I played around with doing the same functionality, only this time with an ActionFilter. My action filter looks like:

```
public class PermanentRedirectAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
    }
}
```

and my action method looks like (I removed a bunch of code to simplify):

```
[PermanentRedirect]
public ActionResult ShortUrl(int id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Post", id);
}
```

My question is this: Did I miss something or is it this simple? I've found some other posts where people are looking to do something similar and they always create a custom ActionResult. Besides using less overall code, given that this behavior may need to be used elsewhere on other action methods, I don't see why it shouldn't be an ActionFilter. With that being said I'm fairly new to the Request and Response objects so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm going to assume that due to the lack of response that nobody has any issues with this. I'll drop a line if I run into any snags with this implementation.

Comment: It seems pretty good solution, i just wondering if you are doing this StatusCode = 301 just for for SEO reasons?, as far as I understand you will expose this resource as an API, so the short URL will just accept HTTP POST and its not intent to be use as a GET for the crawlers and general users.

Comment: You're correct about the SEO reasons. I want him to be able to post http://domain.com/p/245 on Twitter without having to use a shortener and still have the search engines index it under the http://2009/12/12/whatever. I'm confused about your GET vs. POST thought. I have this currently implemented as a GET for the short url route and then does the 301 redirect. Not sure how you would implement this with a POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown will work just fine. However, I recommend using a custom action result instead of using an action filter.

One reason for this is that it will provide more information for your unit tests since there are fewer things to verify. That is, with a custom action result you can verify that the right type of result was used and that it has the right properties set on it. With your current design you'd have to separately verify both the action result data *and* that you correctly applied the attribute.

Another reason is that the code will be cleaner: There will be fewer things for other developers (or you in 2 weeks) to look at or understand. Looking at a simple `return PermanentRedirectToAction("Post", id)` is much easier than looking at an attribute *and* the return data.

Comment: Good point... I did consider the testability of the scenario before I jumped in but since I was just checking the status code of the redirect in Firebug to make sure it was sending a 301 I figured I could just test for the proper RedirectToAction in the unit tests and peek at Firebug to see the 301.

Comment: The other issue I see with the custom action result is that I feel like it's too 'heavy' for this scenario. I don't feel like this is a completely "new" format that deserves its own action result, instead it's just a tiny tweak on the existing functionality of RedirectToAction... Thanks for your thoughts!