# ASP.Net MVC - HTTP Status Codes (i.e. 303, 401, 404, etc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.Net MVC is it possible to use either `Redirect` or `RedirectToAction` to call for example a 303 error?

I am working my way through a book titled "ASP.NET MVC 1.0 Website Programming" and the source is making calls such as `return this.Redirect(303, FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);` but this call only functions with an external library, I would like to have the same functionality sans the add-on if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create custom ActionResults that mimic any http response code you'd like.  By returning those action results, you can easily perform a 303.

I found [this quick write-up](https://web.archive.org/web/20111204040520/http://john-sheehan.com/blog/another-asp-net-mvc-custom-actionresult-example/) that you should be able to follow easily.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I also found this article on Phil Haack's site in case anyone stumbles across this in the future:  http://haacked.com/archive/2008/12/15/redirect-routes-and-other-fun-with-routing-and-lambdas.aspx

Comment: john-sheehan.com link in answer now goes to a Tumblr page requiring a login. Original can be found here: http://johnsheehan.me/blog/another-asp-net-mvc-custom-actionresult-example/

Comment: Now johnsheehan.me is not resolving, and the john-sheehan.com link is 404. Edited to have the archive.org page. This is why it's always better on SO to provide embedded/quoted answers and not just links.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I came up with based on the advice given in the current answers and the decompiled `System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult` code:

```
public class SeeOtherRedirectResult : ActionResult
{
    public string Url { get; private set; }
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode { get; private set; }

    public SeeOtherRedirectResult(string url, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("URL can't be null or empty");
        }
        if ((int) statusCode < 300 || (int) statusCode > 399)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("statusCode", 
                        "Redirection status code must be in the 3xx range");
        }
        Url = url;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        if (context.IsChildAction)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot redirect in child action");
        }

        context.Controller.TempData.Keep();
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int) StatusCode;
        context.HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation =
                     UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(Url, context.HttpContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

2 ways about this-

```
  Response.Redirect(url, false); //status at this point is 302
  Response.StatusCode = 303;
```

-or-

```
  Response.RedirectLocation = url;
  Response.StatusCode = 303;
```

Note that in the first redirect, that the false parameter avoids the threadAbort exception that the redirect(url) normally throws. This is one good reason to use one of these 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

You could also accomplish it with a custom ActionFilter like I mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891324/is-it-ok-to-send-a-301-redirect-with-an-action-filter). I for one like the ActionFilter a bit more the the ActionResult.